# delete XML node using javascript in firefox

Tags: javascript, xml

Im trying to delete a node in XML file using Javascript. The used browser is Firefox. Im reaching the node which I want to delete successfuly, then Im trying 
delNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(delNode)
but when i went back to the xml file on my harddisk, the node was still there. I need to delete the whole node (not only children). If someone could guide me to what to do, I'll be so greatful ;)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I couldn't find a way to change the content of the file in javascript so I used PHP. I was trying simply to delete the first node in my xml **activity1.xml**. Here is the code:

```
$xdoc = new DomDocument;
$xdoc->Load('images\activity\activity1.xml');
$xdoc->documentElement->removeChild($xdoc->documentElement->childNodes->item(1));
$xdoc->save('images\activity\activity1.xml');
```

It simply delete the first node whatever children it has ;)

Answer (score 1):

That should remove delNode. Are you getting an error? What is the result of delNode.parentNode.removeChild(delNode) ? I do the same thing all the time and it works for me.

I'm sorry I missed the part about writing it back to the file. Use [nsiFile](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/embedding/embedapiref/embedapi46.html) to do that and a [chrome:// url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/The_Chrome_URL). In order to take advantage of these things you'll probably have to create a directory with a directory called 'chrome' which will have your script, a [chrome.manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration) file.

Comment: Thanks for answering. when implementing this method delNode.parentNode.removeChild(delNode), my code stop on this line and doesn't do the rest of the functions. I tried another way by
y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file")[0];
window.alert(y);
xmlDoc.documentElement.removeChild(y);
In the latter case, i didn't get an error and all the code was implemented in my browser, but when i went back to the xml file on my harddisk, the node was still there. I don't know whats wrong since it is the first time i try this.
Any idea! and thanks a lot

Comment: Erm. Altering the DOM only changes your in-memory loaded copy, it doesn't write back to the file you loaded it from. You would need to re-serialise the DOM back to an XML file to replace the disc copy. If you are in a web page (not browser chrome) you will have no access to write to the local filesystem at all.

Comment: Oh I missed that whole part about writing it back to file. That's right you need to use the chrome:// url and nsiFile class to write the file to disk.

Comment: Updated answer with relevant information that should help you hopefully.